# First android project build error

Tags: java, android, ant

im just experimenting with Android + Java.

Im following this guide:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Did everything just as it is. I've only changed "DisplayMessageActivity" class name to " DisplayMsgActivity"
I've updated the manifest, and all references to this class, but Im still getting 2 errors:

```
-compile:
[javac] Compiling 4 source files to /home/juanchi/Dropbox/Dev/ArrayAppProject/bin/classes
[javac] /home/juanchi/Dropbox/Dev/ArrayAppProject/src/com/jnix/arrayapp/DisplayMsgActivity.java:7: duplicate class: DisplayMsgActivity
[javac] public class DisplayMsgActivity extends Activity {
[javac]        ^
[javac] /home/juanchi/Dropbox/Dev/ArrayAppProject/src/com/jnix/arrayapp/ArrayAppActivity.java:20: cannot access com.jnix.arrayapp.DisplayMsgActivity
[javac] bad class file: RegularFileObject[/home/juanchi/Dropbox/Dev/ArrayAppProject/src/com/jnix/arrayapp/DisplayMsgActivity.java]
[javac] file does not contain class com.jnix.arrayapp.DisplayMsgActivity
[javac] Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
[javac]         Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMsgActivity.class);
[javac]                                          ^
[javac] 2 errors
```

BUILD FAILED
/home/juanchi/android-sdks/tools/ant/build.xml:680: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/juanchi/android-sdks/tools/ant/build.xml:693: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 5 seconds

Any ideas?

Comment: Please upload your class file somewhere where we can view it. :)

Comment: Are you not using Eclipse with ADT? Try recreating your build file: android create project --target 8 --name "MyFirstProject" --path /path/to/project --activity StartingActivity  --package net.sample.package. And then use ant, "ant debug" to build.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GCkQqL7b here are the *java and manifest files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone uses eclipse for learning and development.  Just create projects in eclipse.  You can import the source into your eclipse project and go from there.  I would start with basic project inside eclipse not outside.  Its way more frustrating to work outside eclipse.  There are many other reasons to use eclipse, like good view of logcat, debugging etc.

Comment: Ive installed latest eclipse but have issues with ADT plugin, then with the text view, and later with syntax errors that were not correct. I didnt have a good experience with it... Maybe I would try again!

Answer (score 1):

try to declare:

```
package com.jnix.arrayapp
```

on the top of the file DisplayMsgActivity

Answer (score 0):

Clean and build the project. sometimes it works.